# (Angular Universal) - firebase.initializeApp is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I have problem with running server-side rendering together with `angularfire2`.

The nodeJS yields:

`TypeError: firebase.initializeApp is not a function`

While browser build work as expected. Is there any trick which should be done to get a server-side rendering with `angularfire2`? So far I am initializing app:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

In the `app.module.ts` which is imported by server and browser modules.

Comment: your firebase sdk is not installed. Usually, this happens when your script is included BEFORE the firebase.js script.

Comment: What do you mean by `firebase.js` script? This one which is included by `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';`?

Comment: If you're using `angularfire2`, why don't call `AngularFireModule#initializeApp` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Did you ever get a working solution for this?  I'm running into the same problem in a non-angular typescript project.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';
```

And then:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Results in :

```
app.core.js:2316 TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

That's in the browser after the build process.

The compiled `app.js` looks like:

```
    undefined(firebaseConfig);
```

**UPDATE** : I just noticed this in my build process:

```
[ WARN  ]  Bundling Warning
           'initializeApp' is not exported by 'node_modules/firebase/app/dist/index.esm.js'
```

**UPDATE 2** : I modified my import and all is working well!

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

Based on : https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/392#issuecomment-389197920